# Dataframe to dictionary with list of items

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, apply

I have this Dataframe:

```
df = 
     key value
0    1   kpi1
1    1   kpi2
2    1   kpi3
3    2   kpi4
4    2   kpi5
```

And I am trying to create a dictionary where for the same key, there's a list of values, like this:

```
d = {'1': ['kpi1', 'kpi2', 'kpi3'], '2': ['kpi4', 'kpi5']}
```

I have tried to use df.apply but I couldn't find a solution. Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`df.groupby('key')['value'].apply(list).to_dict()`

Result:

`{1: ['kpi1', 'kpi2', 'kpi3'], 2: ['kpi4', 'kpi5']}`